# Laravel Mail Smtp php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

everything was working fine with sending mails until yesterday with smtp in laravel but all of sudden this exception is comming from server

`"message": "Connection could not be established with host [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]`

i tried my best but still no luck, my config are correct but still the error here is my smtp mail config

**MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=zizutechnologies.com MAIL_PORT=465 MAIL_USERNAME=no_reply@zizutechnologies.com MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXX MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no_reply@zizutechnologies.com MAIL_FROM_NAME="zizutechnologies"**

Answer (score 0):

Is your laravel application running on a private instance or a private server? To find out, try pinging from your server to zizutechnologies.com. If it does not connect successfully, it means that the server does not recognize the address. What I usually do is add it in hosts file (/etc/hosts if it's a linux server).

`ip_zizutechnologies.com zizutechnologies.com`